# How to get value which has no pair (LOG_IN has no LOG_OUT pair acording to sessionID)

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a report for an application and I have a problem that I don't know how to solve it. I have a table of Username, Date_time, Event and SessionID data. Every LOG_IN and LOG_OUT pair has unique sessionID. I would like to extract that ones, where LOG_IN has no LOG_OUT pair acording to sessionID. If posible I'd like to have it done in MYSQL if not, then in PHP.

There is a code, that gives me table of all events (LOG_IN and LOG_OUT):

```
SELECT username, date_time, event, sessionID FROM userevent
WHERE username like 'User1'
AND date_time BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 500 DAY) AND (NOW() + INTERVAL 1   DAY)
ORDER BY date_time DESC
```

Table:

```
Username    Date_time        Event           SessionID
User1   5.3.2015 13:26:50   LOG_IN  a1e02a779d403df0b7ddd099db14
User1   5.3.2015 11:10:48   LOG_OUT 72651b92ffd2cc5890548fdafe91
User1   4.3.2015 23:37:03   LOG_IN  72651b92ffd2cc5890548fdafe91
User1   4.3.2015 23:36:50   LOG_OUT b10a40d99c9b0eae3d5cbc8947a0
User1   27.2.2015 12:44:00  LOG_IN  b10a40d99c9b0eae3d5cbc8947a0
User1   27.2.2015 12:22:14  LOG_OUT ff210bb81e7550d7d5b24df11d55
User1   22.2.2015 6:20:51   LOG_IN  ff210bb81e7550d7d5b24df11d55
User1   22.2.2015 6:20:15   LOG_OUT c9b40e6eec5616a90573979b54fd
User1   18.2.2015 12:13:15  LOG_IN  c9b40e6eec5616a90573979b54fd
User1   18.2.2015 12:08:41  LOG_OUT 83f068cd8c9c04b1f955495d8c59
User1   14.2.2015 13:20:06  LOG_IN  83f068cd8c9c04b1f955495d8c59
User1   14.2.2015 13:07:36  LOG_OUT 7de97a3caf613ac3bb08dc494c6e
User1   14.2.2015 11:34:46  LOG_IN  7de97a3caf613ac3bb08dc494c6e
```

Now i need a query to extract that ones, where LOG_IN has no LOG_OUT pair according to sessionID. This is how result must look like:

```
Username    Date_time        Event           SessionID
User1   5.3.2015 13:26:50   LOG_IN  a1e02a779d403df0b7ddd099db14
```

Every other events has LOG_IN and LOG_OUT pairs according to sessionID.

I am stuck here and any help would be welcome and i am grateful for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT username, date_time, event, sessionID FROM userevent
WHERE username like 'User1'
AND date_time BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 500 DAY) AND (NOW() + INTERVAL 1   DAY)
AND sessionID NOT IN (SELECT sessionID FROM userevent WHERE event = 'LOG_OUT')
ORDER BY date_time DESC`

Just like your code but added WHERE NOT IN statement that will make sure sessionID that has been logged out is not retrieved by the query.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as

```
select 
username,
Date_time,
Event,SessionID,
sum(Event='LOG_IN') as login_count, 
sum(Event='LOG_OUT') as logout_count 
from userevent 
group by username,SessionID 
having login_count = 1 and logout_count = 0 ;
```